# Determine servlet to handle response in filter

Tags: java, servlets

I want to be able to determine the servlet that will handle a request as part of a Filter implementation.  In the filter code, I want to examine the annotations on that servlet and make decisions on what the filter does based on those annotations.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536950/is-it-possible-for-a-servlet-filter-to-work-out-which-servlet-will-handle-the-re) basically asks the same question, but the accepted answer is to configure the mapping from URLs to filters so that the filter is only invoked for a specific set of URLs.  I don't want to have to resort to this if I can avoid it.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A filter serves as a layer in your web app before and largely independent of the servlet layer.  Why do you want to do this?  Can you explain your business logic more thoroughly?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I am doing a check to ensure that the user is authenticated, which needs to happen for some services and not for others; the filter is the code that is checking for authentication.  I'd like to annotate the methods that don't require authentication and then check for the presence of the annotation in the filter code.

Comment: @ryanmcfall: Why don't you use container based security? With that you can specify `@ServletSecurity` annotations for some servlets and specify the allowed roles.

Comment: @vanje - mostly because I don't want to spend the time to become familiar with more framework code.  Most of the tutorials and documentation that I can find related to doing this are quite verbose.  Also for our application, there are a large number of ways that users might be authenticated, and we have custom auth code to handle this requirement.  The login page would need to be different based on the URL that is being requested.  If you think that container based security can handle these requirements, I'd appreciate pointers to good resources on making it work within a Tomcat environment.